# Не могу разобраться с работой qt_wrap_ui (cmake qt)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Использую clion и соответственно cmake. 
Мне понадобились .ui файлы (MainWindow.ui). 
И я так понял, что для их использования надо в CMakeLists прописать команду `qt_wrap_ui`.
В документации написано, что ее надо использовать так:

```
qt_wrap_ui(resultingLibraryName HeadersDestName SourcesDestName SourceLists ...)
```

Не могу понять, что означают параметры `HeadersDestName` и `SourcesDestName`.

Comment: UI файл -- исходник, из которого генерируется _*.cpp_ и _*.h_ файлы, компилирующиеся во время сборки проекта.

Comment: Предположительно должно быть так: `qt_wrap_ui(your_lib_name ui_your_mainwindow.h ui_your_mainwindow.cpp your_mainwindow.ui)`. Не проверял, т.к. не пользуюсь `cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `qt_wrap_ui` очень древняя. И я ни разу не встречал её в документации [CMake по QT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html). И, судя по всему, она работает только с Qt3.

## Ответ на вопрос "что значат `HeadersDestName` и `SourcesDestName` параметры?".

Это переменные в которые будут сложены пути к сгенерированным файлам '.h' и '.cxx' соответственно. Используются **примерно** так:

```
qt_wrap_ui(mylib ui_headers ui_sources ${ui_source_files})
add_executable(myapp ${ui_headers} ${ui_sources} ${main_sources})
```

Её имя очень похоже на две функции немного новее: `qt4_wrap_ui` и `qt5_wrap_ui` которые являются частью Qt4 и Qt5 соответственно. Заметь что это не функции `CMake` в отличие от `qt_wrap_ui`.

## Ответ на потенциальный вопрос "что использовать вместо этого для  Qt5?"

Сейчас есть два основных способа сборки Qt5 проекта при помощи CMake:

### CMake подход

Достаточно включить `set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)` и CMake автоматически найдет все файлы для которых нужно сгенерировать `ui_*.h` файлы и добавит необходимые шаги компиляции.

### QT подход

Если по каким-то причинам не получается использовать `AUTOUIC`, то можно взять `qt5_wrap_ui` функцию. Но тут нужно добавить пару шагов.

1. Найти все `.ui` файлы
2. Вызвать функцию `qt5_wrap_ui(ui_files "<все .ui файлы>")
3. Добавить сгенерированные файлы `ui_files` в список всех остальных файлов кода в этом проекте `add_library(mylib "<исходные файлы проекта>" ${ui_files})`